# React-native - screen on iOS is not updated even if render method is called

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, render, setstate

I am working on mobile app and I've run into problem which I don't know how to resolve.

I have to load some data from API after creating a screen. I do this in `componentDidMount` method which is `async` so I can use `await` keyword. After that I am setting state so the Loader component (which is just modal displaying text) is hidden and the screen is rerendered with data from API. This works fine on Android devices. But running this code on iOS (iPhone X) doesn't work. The render methods of `SomeScreen.js` and `Loader.js` are called and `Loader.js` render method is returning null (checked with console) but the view on iPhone is not updated. Loader modal is still there even when its render method is returning null. Am I doing anything wrong? Calling `this.foceUpdate()` doesn't help either.

`SomeScreen.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Loader from 'components/Loader/Loader';

export default class SomeScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: true,
            data: []
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const data = await this.loadData();
        this.setState({loading: false, data: data})
    }

    async loadData() {
       //fetch and return data from API
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Loader loading={this.state.loading}/>
                //other rendering...
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
```

`Loader.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Loader extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        loading: false
    };

    render() {
        if (this.props.loading !== true) {
           return null;
        }
        return(
          <Modal
              transparent={false}
              animationType={'none'}
              visible={true}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1, justifyContent: "center"}}>
              <Text>Loading data...</Text>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you see a difference between iOS and Android, but I think you could try simplifying the render method of the `Loader` component. That way you will avoid using 2 `return` calls.

```
import React, {Component, Fragment} from 'react';

render() {
  return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.loading ? null : {
         <Modal
           transparent={false}
           animationType={'none'}
           visible={this.props.loading}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1, justifyContent: "center"}}>
              <Text>Loading data...</Text>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        }
      </Fragment>
    )
}
```

The code above checks the `loading` prop and loads the `Modal` component, or nothing. I also added the `this.props.loading` prop as a value to the `visible` prop of your modal. I think that may have been missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I've found answer. It is because there is opening animation on modal on iOS even if I set `animationType` as `none`. And if I change `loading` as `false`, before this animation is fished, the modal is still opened. The animation approximately takes about 550  ms and my API call takes about 200 ms.

`Loader.js`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Modal, Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Loader extends Component {
    static defaultProps = {
        loading: false
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            loading: props.loading
        };
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
        if (this.state.loading === true && nextProps.loading === false) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({loading: false});
            }, 600);
        }
        if (this.state.loading === false && nextProps.loading === true) {
            this.setState({loading: true});
        }
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading !== true) {
           return null;
        }
        return(
          <Modal
              transparent={false}
              animationType={'none'}
              visible={this.state.loading}>
            <View style={{backgroundColor: "white", flex: 1, justifyContent: "center"}}>
              <Text>Loading data...</Text>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

Basically in my solution I make sure that modal is closed with 600 ms delay so it has time to finish its popup animation.